# Why do I never get the ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: dispose, idisposable

My test method looks like this:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer _myTimer;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (_myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000))
        {
            _myTimer.Elapsed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"timer elapsed");
            _myTimer.AutoReset = true;
            _myTimer.Enabled = true;
            Thread.Sleep(4000); // let the timer fire a couple of times
        } // dispose timer?

        Thread.Sleep(2000); // timer won't fire here
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"no problem accessing _myTimer: {_myTimer.Interval}"); // this won't throw an ObjectDisposedException on _myTimer
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"no problem accessing _myTimer: {_myTimer.Interval}"); // still no ObjectDisposedException
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
        }

        try
        {
            //_myTimer.Start(); // throws the ObjectDisposedException
            _myTimer.Dispose(); // does not throw the ObjectDisposedException
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
        }            

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"no problem accessing _myTimer: {_myTimer.Interval}"); // still no ObjectDisposedException
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I would expect to get the `ObjectDisposedException` after leaving the `using` block.

Accessing the `_myTimer.Interval` works all the way to the end of the program. Also, I can call `_myTimer.Dispose()` anytime. Even waiting for the `GarbageCollector` does not help to get the `ObjectDisposedException`.

However, I do get the `ObjectDisposedException` if I call `_myTimer.Start()` after leaving the `using` block.

How can `_myTimer` be around for the entire lifetime of my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Dispose` doesn't remove the object or references to it. It will not be GCed as long as there are references to it. `Dispose` releases unmanaged resources within the object, which is *likely* but by no means guaranteed to cause at least some of its methods to stop working and start throwing `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that mean that I should always set _myTimer=null after leaving the using to free up the memory? Like leaving the using releases the unmanaged resources of the timer, and the _myTimer=null sends the rest to the GC?

Comment: If you declare it in the `using` instead of declaring it as a static field, you won't need to null it out. (`using var _myTimer = ...` instead of `using _myTimer = ...`) It will become unreachable and eligible for GC when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Sure. In my „real program“ the object is not a timer but my own disposable class. In the using statement I have a long running while loop that polls ConcurrentQueues of that class. Those ConcurrentQueues must be accessible from other threads...